# Semantic UI conditional property based on device type

Tags: responsive, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm looking at the [Semantic UI React docs for Grid](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/) and I want to apply certain column properties only on mobile. E.g.

```
  <Grid.Column verticalAlign='middle' textAlign='right' computer={8} mobile={16} tablet={8}>

  </Grid.Column>
```

On mobile I want `textAlign` to be `center` and on computer I want to be as it is - `right`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that your `Grid.Column` will render on **all devices** but differs only in width. Your `verticalAlign` property and `textAlign` property will apply to each device since you pooled these properties to all devices.

If you want to have different property values then you need to make multiple `Grid.Column` that specifies whether it is `mobile`, `tablet`, or `computer` using the `only` property. Additionally, you can specify the width by using the `width property`

You can also mix and match where you'd like to render it.

Here is an example that shows what I've described above along with your specified widths.

```
<Grid.Column only = {"computer"} textAlign = {"right"} width = {8}>
    Text align to the right of a column size 8 and renders ONLY on computers
</Grid.Column>

<Grid.Column only = {"tablet"} textAlign = {"left"} width = {16}>
    Text align to the left of a column size 16 and renders ONLY on tablets
</Grid.Column>

<Grid.Column only = {"mobile"} textAlign = {"center"} width = {16}>
    Text align to the center of a column size 16 and renders ONLY on mobile devices
</Grid.Column>

<Grid.Column only = {"mobile tablet"} textAlign = {"center"} width = {16}>
    Text align to the center of a column size 16 and renders ONLY on mobile devices AND tablets
</Grid.Column>
```

Comment: It's cool if you have different component for every breakpoint. What if I want to display the same component for both: mobile and tablet. If I attach it like this it will cause rendering every time even if it's invisible.